# ServiceStack metadata json fails

Tags: metadata, servicestack

I have a simple method DateTimeNow, which returns DateTime.Now.

When starting the project in Visual Studio, I get to the /metadata page and I can see the method listed as:

```
Operations:
DateTimeNow     XML  JSON
```

When clicking the XML link, I get:

```
<DateTimeNowResponse xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyServices.DTO">
  <Result>0001-01-01T00:00:00</Result>
</DateTimeNowResponse>
```

But when clicking the JSON link, I get:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime.
Parameter name: value
```

I started by creating the project as shown on http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/

I am using version 3.9.46:

```
ServiceStack.3.9.46\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll
ServiceStack.3.9.46\lib\net35\ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.dll
ServiceStack.Common.3.9.46\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Common.dll
ServiceStack.Common.3.9.46\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll
ServiceStack.Text.3.9.46\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Text.dll
```

The Visual Studio 2012 project uses .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: Verified that this works on ServiceStack version 3.9.35. I got the following result from the JSON metadata rendrer:

{"Result":"\/Date(-62135596800000+0100)\/"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON dates use the JavaScript Date object, which represents dates as the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC. You are converting a time that is before then so it can't be represented.

Comment: Seems like there is a bug in the 3.9.46 json metadata generator for ServiceStack then, because I think this worked on earlier versions.

Comment: I can confirm that there is a bug in that version. I have just upgraded to 3.9.48, and the issue has gone.